Why can't a time complexity O(2^N ) be reduced to O(2*2*2*...*2^0)=O(1)?
Consider the time complexity O(5N2). By eliminating the constant factor 5, we represent the time complexity as O(N2).
Now, if we have a time complexity of O(2N), we can rewrite this as O(2⋅2N-1). Then by eliminating the constant factor 2, we can rewrite it again as O(2N-1).
However, if we continue this process indefinitely, reducing the exponent each time, the time complexity would eventually be (20), or O(1).
What is the flaw in this logic?

"reducing the exponent each time, the time complexity would eventually be (2^0)" - yes, but you would have to do that infinitely number of times, because big O is an asymptotic analysis (i.e. refers to n growing to infinity). BTW - you can apply your argument to any complexity - O(n) can also be reduced to O(1) if you subtract 1 infinitely number of times.

To use your trick, you need to know N ahead of time. So for N=10, you may indeed say the algorithm is O(1) if you know N will always be 10. But it is more interesting to know what the complexity is for general N. In this case you cannot apply your trick because you don't know how many times to apply it. You can bring it down to, say O(2^(N-10)), but that is still the same as O(2^N).

I'd like to expand on @wohlstad's comment with a little more detail. In your question, you write:

However, if we continue this process indefinitely, reducing the exponent each time, the time complexity would eventually be (2^0)

The thing is, the time complexity will never be zero, even if you do this indefinitely. Since N is arbitrarily large, you can always subtract one more from it and still be left with a positive number, no matter how many times you do it. Therefore, you can never get to O(20), even with an indefinite number of iterations.
Another way to think about this is to consider the definition of Big O notation. This approach doesn't identify the flaw in your logic, but it does prove its existence. To paraphrase Wikipedia:

A function f(x) is order O(g(x)) if for some positive real number M, |f(x)| ≤ M * g(x) for all x past a certain point.

That is, f(N) = 5N2 is order O(N2) because for all N > 0 (or any other number, for that matter), |5N2| ≤ 5 * N2. In this example, M is the positive real number 5.
But if you applied your method, M wouldn't be a positive real number. It would be the infinite product 2*2*2*2*2..., which diverges and is not real. That means f(x) can't be O(1), so any argument that it is O(1) must have some fatal flaw.
